# Import github library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to import this library in Android Studio:
https://github.com/lopspower/CircularFillableLoaders?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2897

After import "this", add "that" dependency, update "over there" and Android Studio ends up like this:

[image]

Here's the stack errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1e4e9ec
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor611.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:145)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1359)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:989)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:612)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:578)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1001)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1010)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:678)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.onChildAnimatorEnded(AnimatorSet.java:807)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:640)
    at com.mikhaellopez.circularfillableloaders.CircularFillableLoaders.setProgress(CircularFillableLoaders.java:366)
    at com.mikhaellopez.circularfillableloaders.CircularFillableLoaders.init(CircularFillableLoaders.java:96)
    at com.mikhaellopez.circularfillableloaders.CircularFillableLoaders.<init>(CircularFillableLoaders.java:68)
    at com.mikhaellopez.circularfillableloaders.CircularFillableLoaders.<init>(CircularFillableLoaders.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:441)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:240)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can this error be resolved or is this just the "bug"?
How can I get this work?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of where you use this in Java?

Comment: If you have imported the project correctly, then try rebuilding your project again. These errors will go.